# How to access functions from other files?

Tags: javascript, protractor, pageobjects

This throws error as: 'login is not defined'.

```
//<Common.js>
var Common = function(){
this.login = function(uname,password){
    //All your code that you want to call from the test spec
    element(by.id('txtUserName')).sendKeys(login);
    element(by.id('txtPassword')).sendKeys(password);
    element(by.xpath('//input[@id="btnLogin"]')).click();

};
};

module.exports = new Common();

//<Test.js>
var newPage = require('./Common.js');

describe('The application', function() {

  it('should let you log into the application', function() {
         newPage.login('abcd', '1234');
 });
});


Failures:
1) The application should let you log into the application
  Message:
    Failed: login is not defined
  Stack:
    ReferenceError: login is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update 'login' to 'uname' in below line

```
element(by.id('txtUserName')).sendKeys(uname);
```